# How can I use the time function in a query without writing the where condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

dExpiryDate column is the date column of my table. How can I write ExpiryDate with alias without writing the values ​​less than today in the where condition? I'm sharing an example

```
Select 'CustomerName' = dCustomerName, 
'ExpiryDate' = CAST (dExpiryDate as date) <CAST (getdate () as date) 
from dMyTable
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and desired output. Seems you need something like CASE WHEN CAST (dExpiryDate as date) <CAST (getdate () as date)  THEN ... ELSE .... END

Comment: FYI, the syntax *{literal string} = expression* is deprecated, and should not be used. I, personally, suggest avoiding literal strings at all for aliases; instead use either T-SQL delimiter or the ANSI SQL delimiters (brackets (`[]`) and double quotes (`"`)) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need a case statement like this, I am not clear on the logic you are trying to accomplish as the question was not clear to me on that, but you can fill in the parts of your code below:

```
Select 'CustomerName' = dCustomerName, 
--This does your check for dExpirtyDate needs to be < GetDate(), then set value to dExpiryDate, else put some other value in the column (this part was unclear, so you just replace 'somethinghereDependsOnLogic' with your logic
'ExpiryDate' = CASE WHEN CAST(dExpiryDate as date) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN CAST(dExpiryDate as date) ELSE 'somethinghereDependsOnLogic' END
from dMyTable
```

Comment: That's a `CASE` **expression**, not `Case` (`Switch`) statement. The two are quite different and SQL Server does not support the latter.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. How can I SET an ExpiryDate column instead of using case when? What I have to do is exactly Select 'ExpiryDate' = CAST (dExpiryDate as date) <CAST (getdate () as date) as a result of this query, the table should return dates smaller than this day among the dates defined in the dExpiryDate column.